# GWT Interop: Get complete stack trace

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-jsinterop

Given the following simple Java class defined using [JSInterop](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html):

```
@JsType(name = "ExceptionTest", namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL)
public class ExceptionTest {

   public static void triggerTypeErrorWhenNull(Object object) {

      object.toString();
   }
}
```

Which is called in JavaScript as follows:

```
setTimeout(function timerTrigger() {
  function test1() {
    ExceptionTest.triggerTypeErrorWhenNull(null);
  }

  test1();
}, 100);
```

The following stacktrace is emitted when the exception occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
  at toString_0 (local-0.js:76)
  at Function.triggerTypeErrorWhenNull (local-0.js:1319)
```

My question is how to get the **complete stack trace for the error that occurred**; that is a stack trace that includes the location where the JSInterop method was invoked in JavaScript (`test1()`).

Here a link to the project with the complete source code for the example: [ExceptionTest.java](https://github.com/mxro/mxro-gwt-js-interop-test/blob/master/src/main/java/de/mxro/jsinteroptests/internal/ExceptionTest.java)

Comment: The build in your example project can't pass, `de.mxro.process:java-start-process:jar:0.1.1` isn't in maven central.

Comment: Thank you for having a look and sorry for the missing dependencies. I have fixed the build now and tested it on [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/mxro/mxro-gwt-js-interop-test).

Comment: @ColinAlworth I have fixed the dependencies as written before but forgot to mention you. As said in my error description my main problem is that I can't get the stacktrace emitted in a method wrapped with JSInterop to include the location where the JSInterop method was called. If I do a manual `console.trace()`, I can get the full stack trace though. Thank you!!

Comment: Apologies, I was traveling, I'll take a look as soon as I can. I did get the other notification, but on a busy day - an `@` mention isn't required to let someone know.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for the clarification. And, no hurries, I am already most delighted that you are having a look. Anything I can do to help or explain further, please let me know.

Comment: Hi! Did you get a chance to look at this yet? Thank you!